# nodemon not working

Tags: sql, node.js, express, nodemon

When i run nodemon, it shows

```
[nodemon] 1.17.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
```

But when i run npm start, everything works fine. Why is nodemon not working

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sarthakmedia",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-mysql-session": "^1.3.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "mysql": "*",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.4",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  },
  "description": "practise",
  "main": "app.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": "Anita",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The api's don't get called at all. nodemon starts fine though

Comment: It seems to me that nodemon is working fine. What is not working? Can you access to your app locally? Or not?

Comment: when i make an api call, it doesn't send any requests. wheres the requests work fine while using npm start

Comment: Could you share your package.json content? Or at least your npm start rule?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (Do you perhaps mean <sql-server>?)

Answer (score 1):

try this

1. first step
   in package.json file

"scripts":{
"start":"node app",
"dev":"nodemon app"
}

2. second step
   install nodemon as devdependencies
   using code npm i -D nodemon

3)in app.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// routes
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("hello");
});

// server started
const port =process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server started at port 5000");
});
```

4)fourth step

use (npm run dev) in command line tool

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon starts by running the file `./app.js`.
But your start npm script (which works according to your question) runs a different file `./bin/www/index.js`.

I think you should tell nodemon what file is your entry point.
Thus, you should edit the "main" entry in your package.json with the same value, e.g., `./bin/www`. In fact, nodemon reads this value in your package.json in order to know what file to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your app with `nodemon -w ./` when you are in app root directory.
-w stands for looking at the directory rather than 1 JS file. It is usefu; when you have more than 1 js you need to mon[image]